# JPA Specification search list of string contains

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity");
public class MyEntity {
    // some fields
    @Column(name = "languages")
    @Convert(converter = StringToListConverter.class)
    private List<String> languages;
}
```

SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_entity (
    id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
    // some fields
    languages VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

The field `languages` contains comma-delimited list of values `EN,FR,NO`

My task is to select records that contain some language. For example in native SQL I would like to use this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM my_entity e WHERE e.languages LIKE CONCAT('%', 'EN', '%');
```

I have tried to do this using Specification:

```
Specification<MyEntity> specification = (root, query, cb) -> {
    final Path<Collection<String>> langs = root.get("languages");
    // also I tried root.joinList
    return cb.isMember("EN", langs);
};

repository.findAll(specification);
```

But I receive following error:

```
unknown collection expression type [org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.path.SingularAttributePath]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown collection expression type [org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.path.SingularAttributePath]
```

`StringToListConverter` is following:

```
@Converter
public class StringToListConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<String>, String> {

@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<String> list) {
    if(list==null)
        return null;
    return String.join(",", list);
}

@Override
public List<String> convertToEntityAttribute(String joined) {
    if(joined==null)
        return null;
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(joined.split(",")));
}

}
```

Repository:

```
public class MyEntityRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Address, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<MyEntity> {

}
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: If you are using jpa repository then why don' to use native query like which you have mentioned above also just add few things as well  SELECT * FROM my_entity e WHERE e.languages LIKE %:language%  here language would be a variable which you will pass here to replace language field in native query

Comment: can you please show me  your repository class where you have written this query?

Comment: @GauravRai1512 I removed some conditions from example above that works fine. I can't dynamically build native SQL

Comment: @GauravRai1512 I have added repository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a quite old open hibernate issue about this: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9991

Sadly, the only workaround I found was to use a secondary, read-only mapping for languages in your entity, and use that in the Specification.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity");
public class MyEntity {
    // some fields
    @Column(name = "languages")
    @Convert(converter = StringToListConverter.class)
    private List<String> languages;

    @Column(name = "languages", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String languagesString; //No need for setter

}
```

The criteria:

```
Specification<MyEntity> specification = (root, query, cb) -> {
    final Path<String> path = root.get("languagesString");
    return cb.like(path, "%EN%");
};

repository.findAll(specification);
```

Comment: Hey, did you find another solution ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also get the string from the path and use it as below:

```
public static Specification<MyEntity> withLanguageLike(String name){
    return (root, query, cb) -> !Strings.isNullOrEmpty(name) ?
            cb.like(root.get("languagesString").as(String.class), "%" + name + "%")
            : cb.conjunction();
}
```